# different of DB2 Instance User and DAS User

Tags: database, linux, db2

What is different DB2 Instance user (*on my linux machine is : **db2inst1***) and DB2 Administration Server User / DAS User (*on my linux machine is : **dasusr1***) ?

Already search it through google, didn't find any useful information.

When i want create a database, what i should use to create with? **db2inst1** or **dasusr1** ?

and last question, when i run `db2sampl` (to create database sample) as dasusr1 it will make an error like permission denied, but when run via db2inst1 it worked! why that happens?

(ps : i insert '`source /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile`' to dasusr1's .bashrc, so i can run `db2` and `db2sampl` command with dasusr1)

so confuse about it, any reference about it will be appreciated. Thx for advice :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is correct about what the DAS does (DB2 administration server), however, you do not longer have to worry about because it was deprecated in version 9.7, and removed in version 10.1

Many of the function the DAS did, were replace with Data Studio Web Console and Data Studio Client. The DAS were useful to execute remotely commands in the server using the Control Center, but none of these tools exist in the last version.

Why did you use two users? because the DAS was a server daemon that permitted execute commands for all instances, and it kept a kind of job daemon called Task Center. The instance user is the owner of an instance, and in an instance several databases are stored. That means that an instance owner is the Super user in a given instance, but the das user is not a Super user, it was just a helper to execute commands.

db2sampl creates a database in an instance. When using db2inst1, it creates the database with the instance user owner. When using dasusr1, it does not have any privilege at any instance, and that is the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of an explanation on what the DAS does: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/c0004959.html

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0004960.html

It's only required when administering DB2 from certain remote tools. If you have access to the Linux server and can sign in as db2inst1 (or, even better, become that user through sudo), you won't have any need to run commands from the DAS user account.